# Allocate particular request to different threads through java code

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, blockingqueue

I have one query related to java , as I have got two services which is calling a method  parallely , I want that when my one service on which load is more is running it should serve normally, but if the request comes from the second service it should start processing the request of that service , I mean the threads in service one should not be lost can I achieve this using java 8 .
one solution that I thought was that I can make a thread pool of 100 threads and allocate 80  threads to service one and another 20 to other service, but I had one issue in this that suppose my all 80 threads are in use by service one then I will not have processors to process the request coming from second service,
please do provide solution to this question as we need this, if its in java 8 it would be better

Comment: somehow it's not clear how your environment looks like... Why don't you create 2 thread-pools?

Comment: I did not get fully your question.Do you want some kind of priority so that high priority job will get chance first reference.

Comment: yes i want to set priority dynamically when the request comes from one service then my server can process that request and leave the other request which it is processing but do not lose it @gatisahu

Comment: @JohnnyAW we can make two thread pool but how to identify that which request will be handled by which pool and if one pool acquires all the processors then how the second pool will get the memory to execute i mean it will still remain in queue for the first pool to free the resource

Comment: @Oracleninja your service should send some kind of ID or maybe desired priority as a request parameter. If you want to implement priority, look for priority-queue, there should be some implementations for java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: @JohnnyAW i was asking for some kind of answer related to design level, that i could i design this, anyhow through java code  i can manage the priority using priority queue for that i would have to do dirty coding.

Comment: I see, you know about uppercase letters, as there’s an `A` in your text. Can you [edit] your question to use uppercase letters at *appropriate* places, i.e. start of sentences and when saying “I”? In the current form, it’s almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a priority future task.In current java implementation there is no option to provide priority.so You can create your class

```
public class PriorityFutureTask<V>  extends FutureTask<V> {

 private long priority;
 //more code 
}
```

-Define your thread pool  which will extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` .In current Thread pool executor also not support priority.Create own thread pool extending 
`ThreadPoolExecutor` i.e.

```
 public class PriorityThreadpoolImpl extends ThreadPoolExecutor{
     //some code.
   }
```

-In current ThreadPoolExecutor takes blocking queue which provide data in fifo order.You need to modify which will poll the item with highest priority.
 In ThreadPool

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                              int maximumPoolSize,
                              long keepAliveTime,
                              TimeUnit unit,
                              BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
                              ThreadFactory threadFactory,
                              RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

In your implementation modify your pool code to take priority queue.

```
 public PriorityThreadpoolImpl(int poolSize, long defaultPriority) {
    super(poolSize, poolSize, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(poolSize));
    this.defaultPriority = defaultPriority;
  }
```

-Sample code not fully implemented.

```
public class PriorityThreadpoolImpl extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

  public PriorityThreadpoolImpl(int poolSize, long defaultPriority) {
        super(poolSize, poolSize, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(poolSize));
        this.defaultPriority = defaultPriority;
      }

     protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
        return new PriorityFutureTask<T>(runnable, value, getPriority(runnable));
      }
    //more code 
    }
```

Comment: i need that my two thread pool execute one handle each request, problem here is that if first thread pool consumes all the processors then the second pool will wait to free the processor and i want if any request comes from second service it should execute immediately , you can also help on the design level also.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , just i think you can help me in this, like can i do , the same functionality using some other design principle using java or any other approach.